# Check list in list in R

Tags: r, loops, lapply

I have 2 lists, I want to check if the second list in the first list, if yes, paste letters `"a","b"...` to each element in the first list

```
list1 <- list("Year","Age","Enrollment","SES","BOE")
list2 <- list("Year","Enrollment","SES")
```

I try to use lapply

```
text <- letters[1:length(list2)]
listText<- lapply(list1,function(i) ifelse(i %in% list2,paste(i,text[i],sep="^"),i))
```

I got wrong output

```
> listText
[[1]]
[1] "Year^NA"

[[2]]
[1] "Age"

[[3]]
[1] "Enrollment^NA"

[[4]]
[1] "SES^NA"

[[5]]
[1] "BOE"
```

This is the output I want

```
[[1]]
[1] "Year^a"

[[2]]
[1] "Age"

[[3]]
[1] "Enrollment^b"

[[4]]
[1] "SES^c"

[[5]]
[1] "BOE"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `match` to find the index and then use it to subset the first `list` and paste the `letters`

```
i1 <- match(unlist(list2), unlist(list1))
list1[i1] <- paste(list1[i1], letters[seq(length(i1))], sep="^")
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need change to :

```
text <- as.character(letters[1:length(list2)])
names(text) <- unlist(list2)
```

The result is :

```
> listText
[[1]]
[1] "Year^a"

[[2]]
[1] "Age"

[[3]]
[1] "Enrollment^b"

[[4]]
[1] "SES^c"

[[5]]
[1] "BOE"
```